# Get authentication request in Facebook page tab app

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to develop a page tab application in Facebook

Till now I have always developed canvas page apps using asp.net so this will be my first page tab app

And I am stuck on getting authentication request for user info and friend list

I have used Facebook graph toolkit dll developed by computerbeacon but it doesn't solve my problem for page tab

Any c# or JavaScript source code can help me I can use jssdk or C#sdk but I just want to an example or link that I can learn how this is possible in page tab apps

---

I put this code to my page but it says FB is not defined
if I put connect.Facebook, all.js to the head section this time it says fb.login called before fb.init and it dowsnt show the permission window in both ways

```
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div> 
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '396868406993330', // App ID 

        status: true, // check login status 
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session 
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML 
    });

    // Additional initialization code here 
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously 
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document)); 
 </script> 
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
hello world


<script>
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, { scope: 'email,user_likes' }); 

   </script>
    </div>
    </form>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), namely the [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) function, to request for permission on the front end.

Example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

Remember to load the FB JS SDK first. i.e.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have two questions: what is channel url is it the default page of my app? second question is should i put connect.facebook.net to the head section as script?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook-c#-sdk has changed alot from version 5 to v6 beta (last version), there is no longer facebook authentication methods on the server side.. In order to authenticate the user and get some data you need to either.

1. Authenticate from Javascript and post the Access token string by a post request to the server side.
2. Generate the login URL through the facebook-c#-sdk and redirect the user to auth. dialog.

In order to get facebook-c#-sdk v6, use the following command in NuGet.

```
Install-Package facebook -pre
```

For Javascript, just reference the JS Library like simon604 said.

a good way of communicating both client JS and server C# is to create a hidden field contains the access token string.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found this link on facebook 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

it solves my requesting permission problem

now i am focusing on using access token to get user info and friends

thanks for the answers